# Messed up my screen resolution options

Tags: resolution

Recently I downloaded I think something from nVidia, so I could play Battlefield 4 Beta.
Suddenly it changed up my screen, and now the highest resolution I can pick is only 1280 x 1024.

Before this, I had 1920 x 1080. I don't know what to do, and I can't set the resolution any higher.

Comment: I would remove the current drivers then reinstall them or simply roll them back.  Likewise specific information on your hardware is required.

Comment: Make sure your monitor matches what the OS thinks it is as well.

Comment: I think I know of a registry workaround to change the screen resolution to a custom value. Are you comfortable with tinkering with the registry?

Comment: @gparyani Given this is an obvious driver issue, why would he want to workaround the easy solution of installing the correct driver?

Answer (score 1):

Per Ramhound's comment, assuming Windows 7:
Control Panel > System > (at top left) Device Manager.
Expand "Display Adapters" by clicking the + next to it.
Selet the nVidia by clicking on it once.
Right-click and choose Properties.
Go to the Driver tab.  Cick on "Rollback Driver".  That should revert you to the last one you had before you did the download.

[image: http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC98120.gif]

It is also possible that you installed a driver that isn't matched to your video card.  In that case, you may be getting a default display driver.  You'd know that by going to the same location, and if you didn't see the nVidia display adapter listed, then you may be on a generic driver.  In that case, you can go to your system mfr's site and download the display driver for your system, or you might have a support CD/DVD that came with the system and included the drivers.  Many systems have all the drivers right on the C: drive;  i.e. Dell usually puts theirs under C:\DELL.